1 Нормальная форма БД
Не очень понимаю, что имеют ввиду «без дубликатов», чтобы таблицу нормализовать к 1НФ.
Таблица с атрибутами sex, name, birthday, если пользователь может указать одинаковые данные
Male Vasya 15.02.1996
Female Anna 06.03.2005
Male Vasya 15.02.1996

Можно создать первичный ключ, но уже будет 2НФ ?

Это говорит о том, что существует хотя бы одно такое сочетание, например из всех столбцов, по которому можно было бы построить уникальный индекс или первичный ключ, который будет однозначно идентифицировать каждую запись. Т.е., в вашем случае-  необходимо добавить синтетическое поле ИД с автоинкрементом, например.
1 Male Vasya 15.02.1996
2 Female Anna 06.03.2005
3 Male Vasya 15.02.1996

Теперь, даже если пользователь может указывать одинаковые данные, поле ИД однозначно идентифицирует каждую запись в таблице.
2 НФ - немного про другое - про вынос из таблицы элементов справочников, в вашем случае - пол и имя, и замены их на соответствующие ссылки на ключи

@ГерманБорисов - ваша формулировка корректней, подправил ответ

Всё равно непонятно, как отличить одного Васю от другого? Полагаю, добавление колонки пароля (и соли) сделает записи действительно уникальными и позволит пользователям с одинаковыми именами логиниться именно в своей аккаунт.

@AlexanderPetrov Так там не понятно, что за таблица и какую смысловую нагрузку она несет. Больше похоже на попытки осмыслить методичку, чем на реальную задачу, т.к. уже довольно давно нормализация БД является желаемым, но не необходимым условием, на мой взгляд
